# How to make enable hls support on gstreamer-plugins-bad building from source ? (Compiling to arm with poky)

Tags: linux, gstreamer, yocto, http-live-streaming, gtk2

I'm to trying to make gstreamer-plugins-bad with HLS support to work in a ARM Device. The device has already gstreamer support and I was able to compile gstreamer-plugins-bad, but couldn't make HLS Demux to work. Every time it says it's missing a plugin.

Here is the code I'm trying to make to work:

```
#include <string.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>

#include <gdk/gdk.h>
//#if defined (GDK_WINDOWING_X11)
///#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
///#elif defined (GDK_WINDOWING_WIN32)
//#include <gdk/gdkwin32.h>
//#elif defined (GDK_WINDOWING_QUARTZ)
//#include <gdk/gdkquartz.h>
//#endif

/* Structure to contain all our information, so we can pass it around */
typedef struct _CustomData {
  GstElement *playbin;           /* Our one and only pipeline */

  GtkWidget *slider;              /* Slider widget to keep track of current position */
  GtkWidget *streams_list;        /* Text widget to display info about the streams */
  gulong slider_update_signal_id; /* Signal ID for the slider update signal */

  GstState state;                 /* Current state of the pipeline */
  gint64 duration;                /* Duration of the clip, in nanoseconds */
} CustomData;

/* This function is called when the GUI toolkit creates the physical window that will hold the video.
 * At this point we can retrieve its handler (which has a different meaning depending on the windowing system)
 * and pass it to GStreamer through the VideoOverlay interface. */
static void realize_cb (GtkWidget *widget, CustomData *data) {
  GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_window (widget);
  guintptr window_handle;

  if (!gdk_window_ensure_native (window))
    g_error ("Couldn't create native window needed for GstVideoOverlay!");

  /* Retrieve window handler from GDK */
//#if defined (GDK_WINDOWING_WIN32)
 // window_handle = (guintptr)GDK_WINDOW_HWND (window);
//#elif defined (GDK_WINDOWING_QUARTZ)
 // window_handle = gdk_quartz_window_get_nsview (window);
//#elif defined (GDK_WINDOWING_X11)
  //window_handle = GDK_WINDOW_XID (window);
  window_handle = gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid(window); 
//#endif
  /* Pass it to playbin, which implements VideoOverlay and will forward it to the video sink */
  gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (data->playbin), window_handle);
}

/* This function is called when the PLAY button is clicked */
static void play_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
  gst_element_set_state (data->playbin, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
}

/* This function is called when the PAUSE button is clicked */
static void pause_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
  gst_element_set_state (data->playbin, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
}

/* This function is called when the STOP button is clicked */
static void stop_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
  gst_element_set_state (data->playbin, GST_STATE_READY);
}

/* This function is called when the main window is closed */
static void delete_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, CustomData *data) {
  stop_cb (NULL, data);
  gtk_main_quit ();
}

/* This function is called everytime the video window needs to be redrawn (due to damage/exposure,
 * rescaling, etc). GStreamer takes care of this in the PAUSED and PLAYING states, otherwise,
 * we simply draw a black rectangle to avoid garbage showing up. */
static gboolean draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, CustomData *data) {
  if (data->state < GST_STATE_PAUSED) {
    GtkAllocation allocation;

    /* Cairo is a 2D graphics library which we use here to clean the video window.
     * It is used by GStreamer for other reasons, so it will always be available to us. */
    gtk_widget_get_allocation (widget, &allocation);
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_rectangle (cr, 0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height);
    cairo_fill (cr);
  }

  return FALSE;
}

/* This function is called when the slider changes its position. We perform a seek to the
 * new position here. */
static void slider_cb (GtkRange *range, CustomData *data) {
  gdouble value = gtk_range_get_value (GTK_RANGE (data->slider));
  gst_element_seek_simple (data->playbin, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT,
      (gint64)(value * GST_SECOND));
}

/* This creates all the GTK+ widgets that compose our application, and registers the callbacks */
static void create_ui (CustomData *data) {
  GtkWidget *main_window;  /* The uppermost window, containing all other windows */
  GtkWidget *video_window; /* The drawing area where the video will be shown */
  GtkWidget *main_box;     /* VBox to hold main_hbox and the controls */
  GtkWidget *main_hbox;    /* HBox to hold the video_window and the stream info text widget */
  GtkWidget *controls;     /* HBox to hold the buttons and the slider */
  GtkWidget *play_button, *pause_button, *stop_button; /* Buttons */

  main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (main_window), "delete-event", G_CALLBACK (delete_event_cb), data);

  video_window = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (video_window, FALSE);
  g_signal_connect (video_window, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize_cb), data);
  g_signal_connect (video_window, "draw", G_CALLBACK (draw_cb), data);

  play_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Play"); //gtk_button_new_from_icon_name ("media-playback-start", GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (play_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (play_cb), data);

  pause_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Pause");//gtk_button_new_from_icon_name ("media-playback-pause", GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (pause_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (pause_cb), data);

  stop_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Stop");//gtk_button_new_from_icon_name ("media-playback-stop", GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (stop_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (stop_cb), data);

//  data->slider = gtk_scale_new_with_range (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 1);
//  gtk_scale_set_draw_value (GTK_SCALE (data->slider), 0);
//  data->slider_update_signal_id = g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data->slider), "value-changed", G_CALLBACK (slider_cb), data);

  data->streams_list = gtk_text_view_new ();
  gtk_text_view_set_editable (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (data->streams_list), FALSE);

  //controls = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
  controls = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), play_button, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), pause_button, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), stop_button, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  //gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), data->slider, TRUE, TRUE, 2);

  main_hbox = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox), video_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox), data->streams_list, FALSE, FALSE, 2);

  main_box = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), main_hbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), controls, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), main_box);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (main_window), 640, 480);

  gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);
}

/* This function is called periodically to refresh the GUI */
static gboolean refresh_ui (CustomData *data) {
  gint64 current = -1;

  /* We do not want to update anything unless we are in the PAUSED or PLAYING states */
  if (data->state < GST_STATE_PAUSED)
    return TRUE;

  /* If we didn't know it yet, query the stream duration */
  if (!GST_CLOCK_TIME_IS_VALID (data->duration)) {
    if (!gst_element_query_duration (data->playbin, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &data->duration)) {
      g_printerr ("Could not query current duration.\n");
    } else {
      /* Set the range of the slider to the clip duration, in SECONDS */
      //gtk_range_set_range (GTK_RANGE (data->slider), 0, (gdouble)data->duration / GST_SECOND);
    }
  }

  if (gst_element_query_position (data->playbin, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &current)) {
    /* Block the "value-changed" signal, so the slider_cb function is not called
     * (which would trigger a seek the user has not requested) */
    //g_signal_handler_block (data->slider, data->slider_update_signal_id);
    /* Set the position of the slider to the current pipeline positoin, in SECONDS */
    //gtk_range_set_value (GTK_RANGE (data->slider), (gdouble)current / GST_SECOND);
    /* Re-enable the signal */
    //g_signal_handler_unblock (data->slider, data->slider_update_signal_id);
  }
  return TRUE;
}

/* This function is called when new metadata is discovered in the stream */
static void tags_cb (GstElement *playbin, gint stream, CustomData *data) {
  /* We are possibly in a GStreamer working thread, so we notify the main
   * thread of this event through a message in the bus */
  gst_element_post_message (playbin,
    gst_message_new_application (GST_OBJECT (playbin),
      gst_structure_new_empty ("tags-changed")));
}

/* This function is called when an error message is posted on the bus */
static void error_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  GError *err;
  gchar *debug_info;

  /* Print error details on the screen */
  gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
  g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
  g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
  g_clear_error (&err);
  g_free (debug_info);

  /* Set the pipeline to READY (which stops playback) */
  gst_element_set_state (data->playbin, GST_STATE_READY);
}

/* This function is called when an End-Of-Stream message is posted on the bus.
 * We just set the pipeline to READY (which stops playback) */
static void eos_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
  gst_element_set_state (data->playbin, GST_STATE_READY);
}

/* This function is called when the pipeline changes states. We use it to
 * keep track of the current state. */
static void state_changed_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
  gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
  if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (data->playbin)) {
    data->state = new_state;
    g_print ("State set to %s\n", gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
    if (old_state == GST_STATE_READY && new_state == GST_STATE_PAUSED) {
      /* For extra responsiveness, we refresh the GUI as soon as we reach the PAUSED state */
      refresh_ui (data);
    }
  }
}

/* Extract metadata from all the streams and write it to the text widget in the GUI */
static void analyze_streams (CustomData *data) {
  gint i;
  GstTagList *tags;
  gchar *str, *total_str;
  guint rate;
  gint n_video, n_audio, n_text;
  GtkTextBuffer *text;

  /* Clean current contents of the widget */
  text = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (data->streams_list));
  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (text, "", -1);

  /* Read some properties */
  g_object_get (data->playbin, "n-video", &n_video, NULL);
  g_object_get (data->playbin, "n-audio", &n_audio, NULL);
  g_object_get (data->playbin, "n-text", &n_text, NULL);

  for (i = 0; i < n_video; i++) {
    tags = NULL;
    /* Retrieve the stream's video tags */
    g_signal_emit_by_name (data->playbin, "get-video-tags", i, &tags);
    if (tags) {
      total_str = g_strdup_printf ("video stream %d:\n", i);
      gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
      g_free (total_str);
      gst_tag_list_get_string (tags, GST_TAG_VIDEO_CODEC, &str);
      total_str = g_strdup_printf ("  codec: %s\n", str ? str : "unknown");
      gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
      g_free (total_str);
      g_free (str);
      gst_tag_list_free (tags);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n_audio; i++) {
    tags = NULL;
    /* Retrieve the stream's audio tags */
    g_signal_emit_by_name (data->playbin, "get-audio-tags", i, &tags);
    if (tags) {
      total_str = g_strdup_printf ("\naudio stream %d:\n", i);
      gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
      g_free (total_str);
      if (gst_tag_list_get_string (tags, GST_TAG_AUDIO_CODEC, &str)) {
        total_str = g_strdup_printf ("  codec: %s\n", str);
        gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
        g_free (total_str);
        g_free (str);
      }
      if (gst_tag_list_get_string (tags, GST_TAG_LANGUAGE_CODE, &str)) {
        total_str = g_strdup_printf ("  language: %s\n", str);
        gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
        g_free (total_str);
        g_free (str);
      }
      if (gst_tag_list_get_uint (tags, GST_TAG_BITRATE, &rate)) {
        total_str = g_strdup_printf ("  bitrate: %d\n", rate);
        gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
        g_free (total_str);
      }
      gst_tag_list_free (tags);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n_text; i++) {
    tags = NULL;
    /* Retrieve the stream's subtitle tags */
    g_signal_emit_by_name (data->playbin, "get-text-tags", i, &tags);
    if (tags) {
      total_str = g_strdup_printf ("\nsubtitle stream %d:\n", i);
      gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
      g_free (total_str);
      if (gst_tag_list_get_string (tags, GST_TAG_LANGUAGE_CODE, &str)) {
        total_str = g_strdup_printf ("  language: %s\n", str);
        gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
        g_free (total_str);
        g_free (str);
      }
      gst_tag_list_free (tags);
    }
  }
}

/* This function is called when an "application" message is posted on the bus.
 * Here we retrieve the message posted by the tags_cb callback */
static void application_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  if (g_strcmp0 (gst_structure_get_name (gst_message_get_structure (msg)), "tags-changed") == 0) {
    /* If the message is the "tags-changed" (only one we are currently issuing), update
     * the stream info GUI */
    analyze_streams (data);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CustomData data;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;
  GstBus *bus;

  /* Initialize GTK */
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Initialize our data structure */
  memset (&data, 0, sizeof (data));
  data.duration = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;

  /* Create the elements */
  data.playbin = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin", "playbin");

  if (!data.playbin) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Set the URI to play */
  g_object_set (data.playbin, "uri", "https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8", NULL);

  /* Connect to interesting signals in playbin */
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data.playbin), "video-tags-changed", (GCallback) tags_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data.playbin), "audio-tags-changed", (GCallback) tags_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data.playbin), "text-tags-changed", (GCallback) tags_cb, &data);

  /* Create the GUI */
  create_ui (&data);

  /* Instruct the bus to emit signals for each received message, and connect to the interesting signals */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.playbin);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::eos", (GCallback)eos_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::state-changed", (GCallback)state_changed_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::application", (GCallback)application_cb, &data);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (data.playbin, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.playbin);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Register a function that GLib will call every second */
  g_timeout_add_seconds (1, (GSourceFunc)refresh_ui, &data);

  /* Start the GTK main loop. We will not regain control until gtk_main_quit is called. */
  gtk_main ();

  /* Free resources */
  gst_element_set_state (data.playbin, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (data.playbin);
  return 0;
}
```

It's a sample from GStreamer tutorial ported to use GTK2. I can compile and even run it but with missing plugin problem. The code works on PC, but not in the ARM Device. It is an Yocto Based device with Poky Linux.

Comment: Did you add `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-hls` package? You can check if PACKAGECONFIG of gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad contains hls too with `bitbake -e  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad | grep ^PACKAGECONFIG`

Comment: By the way, when you have a problem with Yocto, you should tell which Yocto version you use.

Comment: I didn't add it. I've compiled it inside the the platform with gcc, make and installed it with make install. About the version of Yocto, I don't know. I just do a repo init git://git.freescale.com/imx/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp.git -b imx-3.10.53-1.1.0_ga. Does it helps ? About to add gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-hls, what section do I need to add it in local.conf ?

Comment: Try considere using a newer Yocto version, and maybe the freescale community BSP instead of NXP's. HLS previous packagename was "fragmented so you will probably need to add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-fragmented"` to local.conf

Comment: It worked ! Thank you ! Now I'm gonna take a look at how to integrate it with Qt.